# Java get json url Forbidden code

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to receive the json of this url: https://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD
It's accessible by browser, however, program is given me the following error:

```
    GRAVE: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at main.JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(JsonReader.java:28)
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.getTicker(UseCryptos.java:62)
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.get24hrVol(UseCryptos.java:50)
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.<init>(UseCryptos.java:42)
    at main.Main.init(Main.java:31)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:52)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.getTicker(UseCryptos.java:73)
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.get24hrVol(UseCryptos.java:50)
    at exchanges.brazil.UseCryptos.<init>(UseCryptos.java:42)
    at main.Main.init(Main.java:31)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm calling this function, with "vol" and "BTC_USD" as parameters:

```
@Override
    public String getTicker(String info, String coin) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            String[] parts = coin.split("_");
            coin = parts[0]+"-"+parts[1];
            System.out.println(base_url + pairs_path_ticker[0][1] + coin);
            json = JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(base_url + pairs_path_ticker[0][1] + coin);
            //json = json.getJSONObject("priVolume");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UseCryptos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UseCryptos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        switch (info) {

            case "vol":
                return Double.toString(json.getDouble("priVolume"));
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Other used functions:

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I tried downloading the https url you reference using curl and it works fine. I also tried downloading the same url but I changed https to http. I got an html page that says "Object moved to here" whee "here" is the https url. So what is probably happening is that you tried to access the http url rather than the https url. The https url does contain a JSON file.  
You may need to use "-k" after curl to ignore certificates  
I also had to split the json file into 3 lines

```
    curl https://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD > x.json

    FILE: x.json

    {"id":113,"marketName":"BTC-USD","lastPrice":377.23420530,"last24hHigh":377.
    23420530,"last24hLow":377.23420530,"priVolume":0.00060138,"secVolume":0.
    22686111,"ask":347.83114848,"bid":337.55042488,"change":0.13968037854984894}

    curl http://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD > y.html

    File: y.html

    <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object
    moved to <a
    href="https://usecryptos.com/jsonapi/ticker/BTC-USD">here</a>.</h2>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Marichyasana , i tried the code only with htttp, instead of https, could you post the the code that you used? I wasn't successed...